# Cannot see process of service in top or ps

Tags: services, process, top, ps

Status of my Postfix service is `systemctl status postfix`:

```
● postfix.service - Postfix Mail Transport Agent
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/postfix.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Sat 2020-01-11 15:31:02 CET; 14min ago
  Process: 16694 ExecStart=/bin/true (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 16694 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
```

I assume the process of the service is **16694**.

But I cannot see this process using `top` or `ps aux`

Example: `ps aux | grep post`

```
root     16693  0.0  0.4  43472  4404 ?        Ss   15:31   0:00 /usr/lib/postfix/sbin/master -w
postfix  16695  0.0  0.6  43408  7088 ?        S    15:31   0:00 pickup -l -t unix -u -c
postfix  16696  0.0  0.6  43460  7044 ?        S    15:31   0:00 qmgr -l -t unix -u
root     16760  0.0  0.0   6080   828 pts/0    S+   15:49   0:00 grep post
root     18447  0.0  0.4  18616  4212 ?        Ss   Jan07   0:00 /usr/sbin/saslauthd -a pam -c -m /var/spool/postfix/var/run/saslauthd -n 5
root     18448  0.0  0.4  18616  4120 ?        S    Jan07   0:00 /usr/sbin/saslauthd -a pam -c -m /var/spool/postfix/var/run/saslauthd -n 5
root     18449  0.0  0.4  18616  4212 ?        S    Jan07   0:00 /usr/sbin/saslauthd -a pam -c -m /var/spool/postfix/var/run/saslauthd -n 5
root     18450  0.0  0.0  18364   924 ?        S    Jan07   0:00 /usr/sbin/saslauthd -a pam -c -m /var/spool/postfix/var/run/saslauthd -n 5
root     18451  0.0  0.4  18616  4120 ?        S    Jan07   0:00 /usr/sbin/saslauthd -a pam -c -m /var/spool/postfix/var/run/saslauthd -n 5
```

Why is this?

Comment: See [Where the process of the service?](https://superuser.com/questions/1164177/where-the-process-of-the-service)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The architecture of Postfix is quite complex. There's not one single process called `postfix`. Depending on what the server is doing at the moment and how it's configured, there may be any out of more than twenty different processes or daemons running, doing different tasks. The master process is called `master`. Two other process appear in your output for `ps aux | grep post`, [pickup](http://www.postfix.org/pickup.8.html) and [qmgr](http://www.postfix.org/qmgr.8.html).

Comment: But where does the PID 16694 comes from? Is it the now closed shell process that called the service script  `/lib/systemd/system/postfix.service`?

Comment: @MrCalvin `postfix.service` isn't a service script, but basically a configuration file for the init system. Today, many linux distributions use `systemd` to manage what gets started after the system booted, in what order etc. In systemd terminology, a daemon / service like Postfix is a "unit", and `postfix.service` is the "unit file" that basically describes how systemd should handle this unit.

Comment: @MrCalvin With many daemons, you will see the "actual" process in the output of `systemctl status`. But Postfix can theoretically run multiple instances in parallel. So the systemd unit starts all instances (by default only one) and exits. The instances are called something like `postfix@name-of-the-instance`. If there's only one instance, it's called `postfix@-`. So, you can get more information about the one instance you probably have with `systemctl status postfix@-`.